# Can't keep settings when upgrading Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 8 Pro RTM

Tags: windows-7, setup, windows-8

I'm trying to install Windows 8 Pro RTM on top of a Windows 7 Ultimate, but the only option I get when asked "Choose what to keep" is `Nothing`, which seems rather drastic.

A friend of mine tried to do exactly the same thing and was actually allowed to keep all settings and applications, which is exactly what I want to do.

Both Win 7 Ultimate and Windows 8 are genuine, and the keys are valid. I've tried using a Windows 8 instead of a Windows 8 Pro key on the setup but the outcome was the same.

My exact version of Windows 7 is (from winver):

```
Windows 7 Ultimate
Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

I've tried running the setup from a Daemon tools-mounted iso, from a bootable usb stick and unpacking the iso image onto a folder (on a different hard drive than the current installation) and running the setup from there.

Any help/ideas on the matter would be appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if it's because you're going from Ultimate to Pro, which is technically a downgrade, edition-wise? I'm guessing. I've installed 8 so many times the last month my head is spinning.

Comment: I upgrade from Windows 7 ultimate to Windows 8 Pro, so this shouldn't be a problem, see also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions

Comment: Did you move your profiles off the system drive? Windows NT 6.x doesn’t allow you to upgrade if you do this.

Comment: @RandolphWest I went from Ultimate to Pro and was able to keep everything.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, problem solved: The issue seemed to be that I had moved my user profile from `C:\Users` to `D:\Users`. That caused the installation to be unable to keep any of my settings.

After moving my profile back to `C:\Users` I do get the option to keep all my settings and applications in the setup.
I'll have to move it back out of `C:\Users` again after the installation though since my main drive is a not-so-large SSD. Oh well.

Comment: How did you managed to understand what was the problem ?

Comment: @Nison, I looked for setup*.log files, and in the fileI foind, I searched for "compatibility scan." an "hardblock". It wasn't random searching, Scott Hanselman himself helped me along :)